# Parsing XML (encoding ISO-8859-1) with Retrofit2 and SimpleXmlConverter doesn't show correct characters in Android

Tags: android, encoding, retrofit2, iso-8859-1, simple-framework

I am using Retrofit2 and SimpleXML converter in Android. When parsing XML file which is encoded in ISO-8859-1 (I don't have any control over server) special characters (õ, ä) are not displayed correctly. Project and everything else uses UTF-8 encoding. The main Retrofit2 code looks like this (with logger and interceptor for testing)

```
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    private static Retrofit.Builder sBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService (Class<S> serviceClass){

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);


        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Content-Encoding","UTF-8")
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        Retrofit retrofit = sBuilder
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
```

When looking in the logs I can see that parsed XML is already with broken special characters. 
I have also tried to encode from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 like this:

```
private String changeCharsetEncoding(String curString) {
        Charset iso88591 = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
        Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

        CharBuffer curBuffer = iso88591.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(curString.getBytes()));
        ByteBuffer outputBuffer = utf8.encode(curBuffer);

        return new String(outputBuffer.array(), utf8);
    }
```

But it's seems that parsed XML is already broken and there is no way how convert it to UTF-8. I have also tried to change Android Studio settings -> File Encoding to  ISO-8859-1 but nothing works. How to correctly parse this XML to show special characters? Is this error because of SimpleXML parser or other reasons?

Comment: I have the same problem.
I try to do this, but doesn't work:
`new String(myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`

Comment: you could solve it?

Comment: Hi, any solution ?